# Stripe connected account webhook getting fired for wrong event not created with my account

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using stripe for payment to connected accounts and everything is working fine.

But I receive an error mail from the stripe about webhook fails and I check and find that the connected account webhook try to send with a payment intend id which is not generated in the main account.

I can check it's generated for the payment of the connected account.

How can a payment id not generated in the main account and triggering the main accounts connected webhook?

Amazed to find that I can able to access all the transactions of the connected account which is not triggered in the main account.

Comment: There are two types of Webhook Endpoints (normal, and Connect). Did you set `connect: true` when creating the Endpoint? Also, are you using Direct or Destination charges?

Comment: I am using both webhook endpoints but the issue is happening with connect and using destination charges.

Comment: Destination Charges exist on the platform, which means you'll get the events on the platform itself.

Comment: Yes you are right, but the event is not created on my platform, because the Payment intent id is not found in the site but only in the connected account webhook. So I am guessing that the id is generated may be in the connected accounts personal transaction which is hitting my accounts webhook.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not quite following what you're saying. The PaymentIntent for a Direct charge will exist on the connected account, and the one for a Destination charge will exist on the platform. Which are you seeing?

Comment: Thanks, @taintedzodiac,  I had a call with stripe support and they found its happening due to a bug in their platform, hope they fix it soon.

Comment: @SoumitraSarkar any news on the topic? Facing the same issue here.

Comment: We tried reaching out to stripe, but they are also confused and even they did not have a solution for that. So the best part is to try to remove the connected account and then reconnect again with the provider, also we check randomly that our stripe webhook for a connected account is disabled or not, as it cause auto disable.